# Running elastic search Mountain Lion Mac OSX

Tags: linux, macos, elasticsearch

I've been trying run elastic search on Mountain Lion and when I use elasticsearch -f, I get this:

```
org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [La Lunatica][inet[/...]] connect_timeout[30s]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToChannels(NettyTransport.java:671)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:610)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:580)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNode(TransportService.java:127)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.innterJoinCluster(ZenDiscovery.java:337)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.access$500(ZenDiscovery.java:76)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery$1.run(ZenDiscovery.java:290)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /....
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processConnectTimeout(NioClientBoss.java:137)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.process(NioClientBoss.java:83)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here:

http://www.concept47.com/austin_web_developer_blog/errors/elasticsearch-error-failed-to-connect-to-master/

Basically: 
1) Find elasticsearch.yml
2) Uncomment or add in : discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false